# Writing data to text file in table format

Tags: java, netbeans, file-io, filewriter

So far I have this:

```
File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\dir\\dir1\\dir2);
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "filename.txt");
FileWriter archivo = new FileWriter(file);
archivo.write(String.format("%20s %20s", "column 1", "column 2 \r\n"));
archivo.write(String.format("%20s %20s", "data 1", "data 2"));
archivo.flush();
archivo.close();
```

However. the file output looks like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/4gulhvY.png]

Which I do not like at all.

How can I make a better table format for the output of a text file?

Would appreciate any assistance.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Fixed!

Also, instead of looking like

```
    column 1             column 2
      data 1               data 2
```

How can I make it to look like this:

```
column 1             column 2
data 1               data 2
```

Would prefer it that way.

Comment: The ` \r\n` is screwig with the results, try `String.format("%20s %20s\r\n", "column 1", "column 2")` instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\r\n` is been evaluated as part of the second parameter, so it basically calculating the required space as something like... `20 - "column 2".length() - " \r\n".length()`, but since the second line doesn't have this, it takes less space and looks misaligned...

Try adding the `\r\n` as part of the base format instead, for example...

```
String.format("%20s %20s \r\n", "column 1", "column 2")
```

This generates something like...

```
        column 1             column 2
          data 1               data 2
```

In my tests...

Comment: Amazing!, this worked flawlessly, thanks!. I edited the OP for 1 more thing, mind taking a look? Thanks again.

Answer (score 10):

I think you are trying to get data in tabular format. I've developed a Java library that can build much complex tables with more customization. You can get the source code [here](https://github.com/thedathoudarya/WAGU-data-in-table-view). Following are some of the basic table-views that my library can create. Hope this is useful enough!

**COLUMN WISE GRID(DEFAULT)**

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
|NAME          |GENDER        |MARRIED       |           AGE|    SALARY($)|
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
|Eddy          |Male          |No            |            23|      1200.27|
|Libby         |Male          |No            |            17|       800.50|
|Rea           |Female        |No            |            30|     10000.00|
|Deandre       |Female        |No            |            19|     18000.50|
|Alice         |Male          |Yes           |            29|       580.40|
|Alyse         |Female        |No            |            26|      7000.89|
|Venessa       |Female        |No            |            22|    100700.50|
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
```

**FULL GRID**

```
+------------------------+-------------+------+-------------+-------------+
|NAME                    |GENDER       |MARRIE|          AGE|    SALARY($)|
+------------------------+-------------+------+-------------+-------------+
|Eddy                    |Male         |No    |           23|      1200.27|
+------------------------+-------------+------+-------------+-------------+
|Libby                   |Male         |No    |           17|       800.50|
+------------------------+-------------+------+-------------+-------------+
|Rea                     |Female       |No    |           30|     10000.00|
+------------------------+-------------+------+-------------+-------------+
|Deandre                 |Female       |No    |           19|     18000.50|
+------------------------+-------------+------+-------------+-------------+
|Alice                   |Male         |Yes   |           29|       580.40|
+------------------------+-------------+------+-------------+-------------+
|Alyse                   |Female       |No    |           26|      7000.89|
+------------------------+-------------+------+-------------+-------------+
|Venessa                 |Female       |No    |           22|    100700.50|
+------------------------+-------------+------+-------------+-------------+
```

**NO GRID**

```
NAME                    GENDER       MARRIE          AGE    SALARY($)      
Alice                   Male         Yes              29       580.40      
Alyse                   Female       No               26      7000.89      
Eddy                    Male         No               23      1200.27      
Rea                     Female       No               30     10000.00      
Deandre                 Female       No               19     18000.50      
Venessa                 Female       No               22    100700.50      
Libby                   Male         No               17       800.50      
Eddy                    Male         No               23      1200.27      
Libby                   Male         No               17       800.50      
Rea                     Female       No               30     10000.00      
Deandre                 Female       No               19     18000.50      
Alice                   Male         Yes              29       580.40      
Alyse                   Female       No               26      7000.89      
Venessa                 Female       No               22    100700.50
```

Comment: Good Hack ! Worked for me like a charm.

Comment: is there any way to import this in android

Answer (score 1):

You're currently including `" \r\n"` within your right-aligned second argument. I suspect you don't want the space at all, and you don't want the `\r\n` to be part of the count of 20 characters.

To left-align instead of right-aligning, use the `-` flag, i.e. `%-20s` instead of `%20s`. See the documentation for [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) documentation for more information.

Additionally, you can make the code work in a more cross-platform way using `%n` to represent the current platform's line terminator (unless you *specifically* want a Windows file.

I'd recommend the use of `Files.newBufferedWriter` as well, as that allows you to specify the character encoding (and will use UTF-8 otherwise, which is better than using the platform default)... and use a try-with-resources statement to close the writer even in the face of an exception:

```
try (Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(file.toPath())) {
  writer.write(String.format("%-20s %-20s%n", "column 1", "column 2"));
  writer.write(String.format("%-20s %-20s%n", "data 1", "data 2")); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try it that way. Also, care taking a look at the OP?, made a edit asking for 1 more thing. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!. Appreciate all the help. Will take a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter("myObjects.txt");
    outputStream.println(String.format("%-20s %-20s %-20s", "Name", "Age", "Gender"));
    outputStream.println(String.format("%-20s %-20s %-20s", "John", "30", "Male"));
    outputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It also works with the printf in case you want to output variables instead of hard coding

```
try {
    PrintWriter myObj = new PrintWriter("Result.txt");
    resultData.println("THE RESULTS OF THE OPERATIONS\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
            resultData.printf("%-20d%-20d\r", finalScores[i], midSemScores[i]);
        }
    resultData.close();
} catch (IOException e){
    System.Out.Println("An error occurred");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```