# Java: Two parallel column format

Tags: java, formatting

I want to print variables in two columns, but I need to nicely print them. What I have is:

Imagine `var1` and `var2` are string that will be change according to user Input throughout the program. The length of `var1` will affect the position of var2, so the position of var2 will not be parallel. So is there a java method that can customize the print format?

What I want: I want to make sure that both columns will be listed in parallel manner regardless the length of them

What I hace tried so far: `System.out.printf("%s %13s\n", var1, var2);`

```
1)apple   1)bad fruit
2)orange  2)good fruit
3)pig      3)animal <----- off
```

Comment: You need java's Formatter. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: Possible duplicate [Writing data to text file in table format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229140/writing-data-to-text-file-in-table-format/26229246#26229246)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like in C, there is a [printf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm) function. You can pass it `%<num>s` which will print a given string taking up exactly `<num>` characters. If length of the string is less than `<num>`, spaces will be added. So first argument is format in which you want to print and other argument are values which will be formatted. For example, as format you can specify `%d` which will print integer, `%f` which will print float, `%s` which will print string, etc.

```
System.out.printf("%8s %7s %6s\n", "One", "Two", "Three");
```

Here is the code that solves your problem:

```
    String[][] values = {
        {"apple", "good fruit"},
        {"orange", "bad fruit"},
        {"pig", "animal"}
    };

    int maxLength = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            if(values[i][j].length()> maxLength) {
                maxLength = values[i][j].length();
            }
        }
    }

    String format = "%d)%-" + maxLength + "s %d)%-" + maxLength + "s\n";

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.printf(format, i + 1, values[i][0], i + 1, values[i][1]);
    }
```

This is the output of the code above:

```
1)apple      1)good fruit
2)orange     2)bad fruit 
3)pig        3)animal
```

Comment: May you explain how does above code work? what does each argument do. since I am not sure how do i apply the code to my print statement

Comment: I've edited the answer that covers your problem. You can take a look at full tutorial here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm

Comment: i still cant get it to work. i am sorry formatting is really not making much sense to it and im grabbing it really slow. What I have tried so far  System.out.printf("%30", k + ")", j + ")" + var1 + "s" , j + ") " + var2);. so the 30 determines the number of length of the whole string, and fill in with "s" which is space between them, but it ran into unknownformatconversionexception

Comment: What you have is different from what I want. I want the output to be `"1)Var 1 . 1)Var2"` . Since length of Var 1 will affect the placement of Var2, I want to make sure that regardless how long Var1 is, the column of var2 is always parallel. So i essential it is a string consist of two smaller string which is `"i + ")"` + Var1" and `"i +")" + Var2`

Comment: What I have `System.out.printf("%s %13s\n", var1, var2);`
The first column is fine, the second column is still not parallel

Comment: I've noticed that you unchecked my answer so I've edited it. Length of var1 should not be greater than 30.

Comment: Can you explain why the line i have won't work? it looks really similar to your modified answer