# print results to text file in tabular form

Tags: python-3.x, tabular-form

I am currently printing onto console, can I print the output onto a text file in tabular form?

I am trying to write the file with:

```
with open("increment.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(i, mol)
    file.close()
```

Here is the program:

```
import numpy as np

    i: int
    for i in range(1, 100,5):
        mol = int((i*5)/(i+2))

        print('i & mol are:',i, mol)


    with open("incre.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(i, mol)
        file.close()
```

Error message..
file.write(i, mol)

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not tuple

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing data to text file in table format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229140/writing-data-to-text-file-in-table-format)

Comment: You are passing a tuple to the `.write()` method. Remove redundant parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining mol inside of your loop; here is the corrected code as far as I understand your question:

```
    with open("incre.txt", "w") as file:
        for i in range(1, 100, 5):
            mol = int((i * 5) / (i + 2))
            file.write(str(i) + " " + str(mol))
        file.close()
```

This will write your i variable separated by a space, then your mol variable. Note since you haven't specified an output directory, it will create the file wherever your python script is stored.

Here is a more pythonic approach:

```
def write_example(output_path):
    with open(output_path, "w") as file:
        for i in range(1, 100, 5):
            mol = int((i * 5) / (i + 2))
            file.write(str(i) + " " + str(mol) + "\n")
        file.close()


outpath = "/home/some_path_here/test.txt"
write_example(outpath)
```

This produces a txt file with the following contents:

1 1
6 3
11 4
16 4
21 4
26 4
31 4
36 4
41 4
46 4
51 4
56 4
61 4
66 4
71 4
76 4
81 4
86 4
91 4
96 4

Each of these being on a new line.

Let me know if this helped! Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, this helped! Also is there a way to give headers to list of output? For example: i and mol followed by their values onto a text file? I am trying with tabulate, is there any other efficient way, please suggest!

Comment: @user1234 Sorry for the late reply, but I would try the pandas module's to_csv function https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html you can make a dataframe object and then convert this into a csv file.